# Detect 1 mA current with an Arduino

Tags: current-sensor

Which sensor can measure current as small as 0.1 mA?

I have tried many sensors with an Arduino, but none satisfy the requirement.

Power supply 5 V, independent current measurement
I want to measure leakage current of surge arrester like this picture:

[image: surge arrester]

(Original larger image here on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DMQa99cmY8hoeLzexolInRD5xvUGFTCV/view?usp=sharing).)

Comment: What sensors they were and what requirements you have for it? Edit that in the question.

Comment: A resistor would satisfy the 1mA requirement, but there are probably other requirements you’ve not told us. What is the maximum current? What resolution?

Comment: What range of current (minimum, maximum?) What voltage?  What is the load?

Comment: A 1.8 kohm resistor to ground and the other side connected to an analog input pin?

Comment: I used this non-contact current sensor before. But it doesn't meet the requirement.https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity_Analog_AC_Current_Sensor__SKU_SEN0211_

Comment: Basically you don't need a "sensor" to measure a current using an Arduino. The general concept for measusing a current is: 1) the current must flow through a measurement **resistor**. 2) the resistor will develop a voltage when a current flows 3) if that voltage across the resistor must remain small, you would use an **amplifier** (usually a circuit based on an **opamp**) to amplify the voltage. 4) that voltage is measured using the ADC input of an Arduino.

Comment: *I used this non-contact current sensor before* That sensor provides **isolation**. You will need to be much more specific about what current you want to measure. If it is an AC mains current (like what that non-contact sensor is used for) then you **cannot** use the simple scheme I mentioned in my comment above. How to measure a current depends on the complete system and at this moment you're not telling us anything about that so we can only **guess** what you need. So be much more specific!

Comment: I want to measure leakage current of surge arrester like this picture   .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DMQa99cmY8hoeLzexolInRD5xvUGFTCV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A surge arrestor for a 5V power supply? There is a lot you're not telling us here...

Comment: presumably you also don't want the sensor to explode when there's a 1000000mA surge?

Comment: Surge arresters are devices used in **high voltage** and **high power** environments. If you need to ask what can be used to measure the leakage current then you need to take a step back and consult a professional in the high voltage/high current field and get assistance. The picture you show is that of a professional device. I advice you to get such a device and also to get an education to learn how to use it **safely**. If you still think you can do this then provide proper information that shows what you need. At this moment my impression is that you lack the skills to do this.

Comment: And the picture shows a "discharge counter" which is not a surge arrester.

Comment: Looking at the datasheet for what you are trying to replace: https://tinyurl.com/2dbhmy56  ....this device  is placed in series with a surge suppressor and during a surge could have 1kV across it. Rethink your replacement device as you can never assure that you won't see a surge event during measurement.

Answer (score 0):

A resistor between two analog inputs will do the trick...
you can read the voltage difference (analogread) and then the current, this can save you the use of other components.

Arrange the resistor value to read a reasonable int() number for any analog input and then subtract the values.

You have to define by yourself how much "amps" you have for let's say "X" as a int() number you read (that obviously represent the voltage).

just plain analog electronics in digital style.

Comment: I wrote about such a solution in my comment. I also wrote in my next comment that such a solution does not apply if the current needs to be measured in an **isolated** way, for example by using a non-contact sensor (current transformer) and when the current is **AC**. Your answer assumes we're talking about a small DC current at low voltage. Maybe OP is asking about AC at high voltage and that would **blow up** the circuit you suggest.

Comment: sorry, my fault.. i don't see your comment in the "next 5 comment button". anyways my solution was "a direction" how to implement things (in SW and HW) is not my business.